# INSERT OR REPLACE adding a whole new row SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm creating a little stock tracking project using Flask.  I have generally used an ORM, but was trying vanilla SQLite on this.

I have 3 tables, users, stocks and a join table of stocks_users that has a column for user_id, symbol, and quantity

```
            db.execute(f"""
                INSERT OR REPLACE INTO user_stocks(user_id, stock_id, quantity)
                VALUES (
                    (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = '{user_id}'),
                    (SELECT 1 FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '{symbol}'),
                    {shares}
                )
            """)
```

I am running this trying to insert a row if it does not exist, but if a row has the matching user_id and symbol (primary key for the users and stocks tables respectively) I would just like to update the quantity.

Any direction on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You likely want what's known as [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html).

Comment: I agree that the UPSERT is the way to go here, but `INSERT OR REPLACE` is still a valid construct if used correctly.  Look at what you are inserting... *always* a `user_id = 1` OR null if it does not already exist.  (BTW, inserting an explicit NULL does not cause the default value to be inserted.)  That doesn't make sense.  The point of the INSERT or REPLACE is to do just that.. you try inserting a record **just as you want it stored** and if there is a conflict with primary keys, then the original row is deleted and the new inserted.  There is no need for the subqueries selecting a literal 1.